# Track long and failed requests with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, logging, error-handling

Sometimes my app behave strange. Some of my requests start to take for a long time and then could failed, without any system. And after even looking through the logs I can't find such request in it, and it's looks like they even wasn't handled by the server.

So I want to implement clientside script, who will be track longterm or failed requests, and then send this info to server.

What is a best way to implement such a functionality?

Comment: How smart is it to check for server-errors and save them to said server?

Comment: I do not get what you mean.

Comment: Well, if your server fails. It most likely can't read or write at that time. So how can you save a log to the server that just failed? It doesn't make a lot of sense :-p

Comment: No, server is fine more or less. And by the way - it's easily to send logs to the other server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) You can override `XMLHttpRequest` to provide the desired functionality.

```
var mylog = [];    

XMLHttpRequest = (function(XMLHttpRequest) {
    return function() {
        XMLHttpRequest.apply(this, arguments);
        this.timeout = 30 * 1000; //thirty seconds
        this.ontimeout = function() {
            mylog.push("Request timed out");
        };
    };
})(XMLHttpRequest);

setInterval(function() {
    //send to server
    mylog = [];
}, 60 * 1000);
```

(2) You can create your own XHR factory that sets `timeout` and `ontimeout` on them. You much change all your code to use this.

(3) You didn't mention jQuery, so I won't spend too much time on this, but with jQuery, you can use `$.ajaxSetup` to set default parameters.

Really though, you should spend your time trying to track this from the server end; they are much more reliable in gathering what you want.